# MySQL query Select data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Trying to make query for 4 hours. For example i have such data:

```
did   title      number_link    ltitle
35  about.html        1          NULL    <- this
35  about.html        2          NULL    <- this
36  about.html        1          NULL
35  contact.php       1          NULL    <- this  
35  contact.php       3          NULL    <- this  
36  contact.php       1          NULL
```

How to chose distinct title and distinct number_link ?
I have marked with "<-" what i want to get from query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried in 4 hrs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will allows you to get all the column with in the row not just `title` and `number_link`.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  title, number_link, MIN(did) did
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY title, number_link
        ) b ON a.title = b.title AND
                a.number_link = b.number_link AND
                a.did = b.did
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title FROM table GROUP BY title, number_link
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
GROUP BY title, number_link
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT title,number_link FROM table GROUP BY title, number_link;